# Angular2 / Angular-CLI with PhantomJS - "Attempted to assign to readonly property."

Tags: angular, phantomjs, angular-cli

All my tests are passing with Chrome.  When I run my tests (ng test --watch=false) using PhantomJS I get the error 'Attempted to assign to readonly property'.

```
TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. in src/test.ts (line 45994)
        setProperty@webpack:///~/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js:2923:0 <- src/test.ts:45994:11
```

Comment: Have you tried updating Zone.js to the most recent version?

Comment: I am using the latest at this time - version 0.8.10

Comment: I'm going to guess that you are using a feature that requires a polyfill to be activated in order to use it with PhantomJS  If you are using Angular-CLI these would be listed in polyfills.ts

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, did you manage to solve it?